# Event purchase not working GA4 Monetization report not showing

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags, google-analytics-4

I have a problem with the purchase event of google analytics 4
in real time dashboard I see instant conversions but it does not appear in the monetization table, e-commerce purchase
here is the information following the debug

https://ibb.co/bP1XN4m
https://ibb.co/3M3H56y

I verified id tag it is correct why i have in GA debug extension
the message sending event "purchase" to undefined
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

That purchase event is looking correct.
Try this:

1. Events take about 24 hour to end up in GA4 reports.
2. After a day since that purchase event fired see if any data is being pulled into GA4 - Reports - Monetization - Ecommerce purchases.

Then we can debug further

[image]